# Howto toggle scrollbar to all-way-up or all-way-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I am able to force the scrollbar all the way down, by animating it to a div at the bottom. I also know how to animate it back to the top.

But if I have code that catches the fact that I reached the bottom via animation, it either automatically starts going back up. Or after pressing up, it goes into an infinite loop of up and down when reaching the ends.

Or perhaps I should be doing this in a different way altogether?

```
  $("div").scroll(function(){
    if (emergency) return;
    $("span").text( x+= 1);
    if (!atTop() && !atBot()){
       animating = true;
       sayPos("mid");
       if (down)
           txtbx.animate({scrollTop: txtbot}, 10, animdone);
       else // up
           txtbx.animate({scrollTop: 0}, 10, animdone);
    } else if (atTop() && !animating) { 
        animating = true;
        sayPos("top");
        txtbx.animate({scrollTop: txtbot}, 10, animdone);
    } else if (atBot() && !animating) {
        animating = true;
        sayPos("bot");
        txtbx.animate({scrollTop: 0}, 10, animdone);
    } else { // animation end: atEnd but was animating
        ended = true; //animating = false;
        sayPos("endAnim ----------------");
    }
});
```

and

```
function animdone(){ 
    scrlpos = txtbx.scrollTop();
    if(ended){
         if (down && scrlpos > 0)
            txtbot = scrlpos;
         ended = false;
         //animating = false;
         down = !down;
         sayPos("..ended");
     }
     else sayPos("..callback"); 
 }

function atBot(){ return scrlpos >= txtbot;  }
function atTop(){ return scrlpos == 0; }
```

[Here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pashute/hqoo68sp/72/)

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a simple way, in JQuery, using `myelem.scrollTop(target)` and putting a div at the end of the text.

- `myElement.scroll(`... - to catch the event and then
- `myElement.scrollTop(0)` - for scrolling to the top of the element
- `window.scrollTop(txtBottom)` - for scrolling to the bottom, where txtBottom is a div element at the end of the text.

With `scrollTop( somevalue )` I only get one extra scroll event, as opposed to the animation which was creating multiple evens.

The first scroll-event that we catch was caused by the user's click on the scrollbar, and the second event was caused by the code forcing the scrolling all the way to the top or bottom of the element.

If you want to catch the scroll event for the whole window (meaning the browser), you put the div at the bottom of the text and use

- `$(window).scroll(`... - to catch the event and then
- `window.scrollTo(0,0)` - for scrolling to the top of the window
- `window.scrollTo(0,txtBottom)` - for scrolling to the bottom, where txtBottom is a div element at the end of the text.

I catch the first iteratin caused by the user's press on the scroll bar, and push it all the way. I decide which way to push according to the last scroll position. If its zero then it's up and top and needs to go down to the div at the end. Otherwise it goes back up to the zero at the top.

I then simply ignore the second iteration of .scroll, caused by my code pushing the scrollbar on to its end.

```
var isSecondScroll = false;
var lastScroll = 0;
myElem = $("#myelem"); // my scrolling element
// or: myElem = $(window);
txtBottom = $("#myelembottom").offset().top;  // dev at end of text
myElem.scroll(function(){
    if ( !isSecondScroll )
       isSecondScroll = false;
    else { // first iteration
        if (lastScroll == 0) // top
            myElem.scrollTop(txtBottom); 
            // or: myElem.scrollTo(0,txtBottom); // for scrolling full browser window

         else // not top
            myElem.scrollTop(0);
            // or: myElem.scrollTo(0,0); // for scrolling full browser window

    }

    isSecondScroll = true;  // mark for next iteration
    lastScroll = myElem.scrollTop();

}); // .scroll()
```

The HTML would look something like this

```
<div id="myelem" 
     style="width:200px; height:100px; overflow:scroll;" >
here comes long text more than the 100px high
<div id="myelembottom"></div>
</div>
```

[Here's a working corrected fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pashute/hqoo68sp/85/) 
And here's a working corrected fiddle (with cleaner code) [for scrolling the whole browser window](https://jsfiddle.net/pashute/hqoo68sp/88/).